# MQTT (Mosquitto) certificate SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl, python

I'm been desperately trying to get my MQTT clients to connect to my MQTT broker which is set up with a certificate from a CA.

To be able to get the CA certificate, I've used the letsencrypt python command (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/letsencrypt/0.4.1)

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -d www.myserver.com
```

This has given me:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Mar  6 23:50 cert.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Mar  6 23:50 chain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   46 Mar  6 23:50 fullchain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44 Mar  6 23:50 privkey.pem
```

I've put these files inside my /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:

```
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/chain.pem
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/cert.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/privkey.pem
```

And I was able to start the broker, v1.4.8 fine:

```
[ ok ] mosquitto is running.
```

and from the log:

```
1457462631: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Sun, 14 Feb 2016 15:06:55 +0000) starting
```

When I try to subscribe to the test topic, to, well, test, using this command from the client:

```
mosquitto_sub version 1.4.8 running on libmosquitto 1.4.8.
```

Running command:

```
root@titan:~# mosquitto_sub -h www.myserver.com -p 8883 -t test --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/cert.pem --key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/privkey.pem
```

Nothing happends in the command line, so I am assuming that it's listening. Less could be more true, in the log file this pops up:

```
1457462866: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 8883.
1457462866: OpenSSL Error: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol
1457462866: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

I'm at a loss here. Any help is appreciated!